# How to find a sentence spread over mutltiple lines in a multiline string

Tags: c#, string

As the title says.
I have this string read from a file into a string

```
"has anyone really been far even as decided to
use even go want
to do look more like"
```

When I do this, it writes hello world.

```
    if (string.Contains(@"use even go want
to do look more like"))
    {
        Console.Write("Hello world!");
    }
```

but when I do this, it won't work.

```
if (string.Contains(@"use even go want\nto do look more like"))
{
    Console.Write("Hello world!");
}
```

Isn't there a better way to find a sentence spread over multiple lines in a string instead of just planting a return in the middle of the code?

(I've also already tried `\n\r`, `\r\n` and `\r`)

Comment: If you have delimiters like the quotation marks in the example, you can split the string by the delimiter and look for the string in there.

Comment: You could do a `Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ")` on the string you're searching

Comment: @runedisc what about use the array which contains your lines from file and you can work with each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `\n` will be interpreted as `'\'` followed by `'n'` in a [*verbatim string literal*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Removing `@` from your string literal should fix the problem:

```
if (string.Contains( "use even go want\nto do look more like"))
{   //              ^
    Console.Write("Hello world!");
}
```

or you can use `System.Environment.NewLine` if the separator is system-specific:

```
if (string.Contains("use even go want"+System.Environment.NewLine+"to do look more like"))
{
    Console.Write("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: oh god, I'm so retarded :P. Thanks for pointing it out though. (Side note: apperently it has to be "\r\n" because that's what windows uses acording to the internets)